# How does my domain's DNS Server know where to resolve new lookups?

Tags: windows, dns

My computer is on a Windows domain. The domain has 1 DNS server(192.168.1.79). If I lookup a new website I've never looked up before, how does my local DNS server resolve that website? What server does it look at to resolve this? When looking through the DNS Manager on the DNS server I cannot find any reference to an outside DNS server.

This question seems simple but I cannot find an answer on Google. If I'm leaving out any pertinent info let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If not, it forwards the request to the DNS server configured in the network card settings.

That's not entirely correct: the Windows DNS Server has an entirely separate configuration page – the ["Forwarders" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAZDy.png) in the DNS management console – for specifying what server the query should be forwarded to.

But in addition to that, forwarders are not necessary at all because the Windows DNS Server supports doing **iterative queries** all by itself (just like the large public DNS servers do). This process is already documented elsewhere, but in short it works like this:

- the resolver will start by asking the *root* nameservers and will receive a referral to the TLD nameservers (e.g. the ones hosting the `com` zone);
- the resolver will ask the TLD nameservers and will receive another referral (e.g. to the nameservers hosting the `google.com` zone);
- the same process is repeated as many times as necessary, until the resolver finally receives a direct authoritative response to the query.

The ["Root Hints" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzbg4.png) shows you those root nameserver addresses – the list changes so rarely that it's simply included with the DNS server software. The official list can also be found [at IANA](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers).

[image: Forwarders]
[image: Root Hints]

Comment: Ah, the first picture was what I needed. We have some public DNS Servers set in the Forwarders tab, as well as the root hints checkbox checked. Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your Domain controller to have access to the internet itself, it has to have access to a DNS server itself. In the network card settings of your domain controller, it will specify that it has a different DNS server, either that of the router or a DNS server outside of your network, such as that of the ISP or a public one such as 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1.

The DNS server on your domain controller will be the server used by all computers in the domain. When a request for a website is made to the DNS server, it first looks into its local cache to see if it has this domain listed. If not, it forwards the request to the DNS server configured in the network card settings. Once it gets the results, it will cache it into its own local cache, such that the next time you query that address, the DNS server does not have to get a query onto the internet, unless the TTL value states it is too old. Then a new query onto the internet DNS server will be made and the cache value is updated.

If you have everything setup correctly, and you were to change the network cards DNS server to also query from the local DNS server itself, at first, you'll find out that everything seems to work correctly. But once the TTL value has expired and you request a new lookup for an IP address, it will attempt to query itself resulting in a "this domain does not exist" kind of error (the exact error varies between browsers, but should be something like `This site can't be reached.` (`DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`)), and your internet pages will no longer load until the DNS is configured correctly again.

Comment: This makes sense, but oddly our Domain Controller has only itself as as a DNS server. [Here is a screenshot](https://ibb.co/Pt7ykvP). By the way, this works for our computers somehow.